# TypeScript 's type inference feature works fine in case 1 but throws error in another

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, casting, compiler-errors

so i was experimenting with TS's type inferencing feature: i.e. when we dont specify variable type to be number string or boolean and instead leave it to TS to figure it out on its own during initialisation or assignment.

Unfortunately, it behaves in a confusion way

Case 1 -->

```
function func(arg1:number, arg2:string){
console.log(arg1 + arg2);
}

let v ;
v = func;
console.log(typeof v);
v = 8;
console.log(typeof v);
```

the code works fine and the output is : function and number

but in case 2 -->

```
function func(arg1:number, arg2:string){
console.log(arg1 + arg2);

}

let v = func;
console.log(typeof v);
v = 8;
console.log(typeof v);
```

here the TS compiler throws an error:
Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(arg1: number, arg2: string) => void'.

can someone tell me what i am missing??
~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I see it is that in the first case, you declared `v`, and the type of it will be inferred as you write the code. So it didn't had a certain type at the start. Hence you being able to change it multiple times.

In the second case, you already declared it as a function from the beginning. So typescript will consider that, from now on `v` is a function and any type change of it will result in an error.

Comment: yeah but why does it behave like that?

Comment: @AliasD Because TypeScript is a type safe language. It won't let you change the type of a variable that you defined with a certain type at the beginning. This is one of the features that comes with the language. It protects variables from getting the wrong type later in the code.
However, if you don't declare it with a predefined type, it offers you the possibility to change it later.